# How can I communicate with the Websocket using Python

Tags: python, api, websocket, python-3.5

I am having the binary.com API. I am trying to communicate with the Websocket. I must admit that I am naive in this type of programming. I need some help so that it will be easy for me to understand and work it out.
Here is the sample code that they have provided already but I do not know how to program further.

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks':'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('ticks update: %s' % message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Please provide me an example here which I can understand. If you need I can share the API token so that you can try.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, does this code work for you?

Comment: @hurlenko Ok. I will tell you. I am trying to work with authentication and bidding through the API or Websocket that binary.com has given. As I have already said I am naive to this type of programming. Please let me know. The above code only prints the ticks of the currency. I want to perform the authentication and bidding while the websocket is running. I guess I tried to clear. Please let me know.

Comment: Please help me understand how I can bid using the api and websocket client in python

Answer (score 1):

There is a python library for binary.com/deriv.com API

https://github.com/mdn522/binaryapi

*I am the author of the library